# Selective update with pacman / yaourt?

Tags: updates, arch-linux

I´m using yaourt in ArchLinux.

- Is it possible to do a `yaourt -Syu` but only including packages from core/extra or what I want?
- How to update single packages? `yaourt -U <package>` does not work (could not find or read package). Do I have to use `yaourt -S <package>`?

#### EDIT

- There is a problem with using `yaourt -S <package>`: If there is no update available, the package will be reinstalled anyway

Answer (score 6):

For the first point:

> Is it possible to do a yaourt -Syu but only including packages from core/extra or what I want?

According to the documentation, `pacman` (or `yaourt` in this case) will attempt to read `pacman.conf` each time it is invoked. So, did you try to comment the sections you don't want to be upgraded?

For the second point:

> How to update single packages? `yaourt -U <package>` does not work
>   (could not find or read package). Do I have to use `yaourt -S <package>`?

Pacman's install command `-S` it's, in fact, a synchronization. Installing or upgrading are done in the same way:

```
$ pacman -S <package>
```

Or:

```
$ yaourt -S <package>
```

Comment: Ok, but with selective update I meant giving the selection in the command line when doing the update.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **update just one package in Arch Linux**, do the following 
*(please note that **#** indicates that the command should be run as **root**)*

1) Search the package's name with

> **$ pacman -Ss *keyword***

(it prints out here the package's name and other stuff)

2) Run the following command to get the package's URI

> **# pacman -Syup | grep *package's_name***

(write the package's name you got in the previous command, now
you should get the package's uri)

3) Finally, copy the uri and run the following command to update it

> **# pacman -U *package's_uri***

Hope this helps somebody.  As a side note, this is **not the recommended 
way** to update a package.  If possible, upgrade the entire system.  However, 
this is a good way when you just need to update one package and don't have
the bandwith to run a full system upgrade *(for example, I recently needed
to update just the **flashplugin** package)*.

Comment: The method to get the URI doesn't seem to work: `pacman -Syup | grep linux` returns nothing. Further I don't quite get what is the advantage in comparison to `pacman -Sy <package>` - which just updates the packages given.